# Prevent chained git hooks for single repo in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, githooks

We are using Gitlab Community Edition 8.15.2 and are using custom global git hooks for all our repos (i.e. all repos use the same hooks).

For one of our repos, I want to use a `<project>.git/custom_hooks` hooks and NOT the global hooks.
According to the Gitlab documentation for chained git hooks (https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/custom_hooks.html) it's going to go through all the possible locations and execute as long as the previous ones successfully exit.

I don't want it to execute both the `custom_hooks` and the `global` hooks...just the custom one. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, after [gitlab-shell merge_requests 93](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-shell/merge_requests/93), that `<project>.git/hooks/` is a symlink to `gitlab-shell/hooks` global dir.

So if you want to be sure to *not* use global hooks, you would either

- change the symlink to an empty folder (but that might have side-effects if gitlab-shell expects to run for instance a common global pre-reveive or update hooks)
- change the global scripts in order to detect the Git repo they are executed in, and exit immediately (with status 0) if the repo matches one you don't want global hooks.